# Rename the uploaded document in document library using the client side object model

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, .net

I already uploaded the document in SharePoint document library using CSOM.

Now I need to Rename the uploaded file using CSOM, how to achieve this via CSOM?
pls look the code below and do the need full...

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentLibraryLink"]));

context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                Web web = context.Web;
                bool iscontinue = false;

                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(InputFileName);
                newFile.Url = "/" + newFile;

                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentLibraryName"]);
                string strFilename = InputFileName;

                //rename
                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Shared Documents”);
                 docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentLibraryName"]));

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                context.Load(uploadFile);
                 context.ExecuteQuery();

                ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;

                string renamefile = txtfilename.Text.ToString();

                string docTitle = string.Empty;
                item["Title"] = renamefile;

                item.Update();

                 RenameFile(context, strFilename, renamefile);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change file name of an already uploaded document try below code:

Get the uploaded file object using ID/ URL or which ever way suits you, then try this:

```
ListItem item = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;
item["Name"] = "NewName";
item.Update();
// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
uploadFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you want to change file name of the file while uploading try below code:

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    newFile.ContentStream = fs;
    newFile.Url = newFileName;
    newFile.Overwrite = true;
    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Shared Documents”);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: hi Unnien, thanks but its working , how to rename the file name in the document library....

Comment: Just use the snippet above to rename file in a document library.

Comment: can you Please,provide the solution for renaming the file the above code snippet is not working.. please do the need full...

Comment: Could you post the code in the question

Comment: hi unnien, added the code  in the question ...

Comment: Edited my answer